# excel vba category tree taxonomy replace number w/ its correct name. Subcategory is dependent on previous category

Tags: excel, vba, taxonomy

I am attempting to build a macro that replaces the category number with the category name. the category 1 # needs to be replaced by its correlating category 1 name. 
Then for the subcategories (*categories 2 - 6)* need the # replaced with its names. 
A number "1" in **category 2** may translate to the name "Adults" if **category 1** in the same row is a "1".
However, a number "1" in **category 2** that has a "2" in **category 1** would not translate to the name "Adults".
There are 6 levels of categories and not all are necessarily filled.
*must be based on the user selection*
-*goto ErrHandlr if user has selected more than 6 columns*
-*goto ErrHandlr if user has selected entire column*

Structure example: 
~*() indicates contents of cell*
~*the example is a selection of S5-X11 (which changes based on need)*
~*(category 1, category 2,... category6)*

```
(1) (1) (2) (3) (4) ( )
(1) (2) (1) (4) ( ) ( )
(1) (1) (1) (4) (5) (1)
(1) (2) (2) (1) (4) ( )
(2) (1) (1) (8) ( ) ( )
(2) (1) (2) (1) (9) ( )
(5) (1) (3) (1) (1) ( )
```

Desired output Example :

```
(Name1) (Name1.1) (Name1.1.2) (Name1.1.2.3) (Name1.1.2.3.4) ()
(Name1) (Name1.2) (Name1.2.1) (Name1.2.1.4) ()              ()
(Name1) (Name1.1) (Name1.1.1) (Name1.1.1.4) (Name1.1.1.4.5) (Name1.1.1.4.5.1)
(Name1) (Name1.2) (Name1.2.2) (Name1.2.2.1) (Name1.2.2.1.4) ()
(Name2) (Name2.1) (Name2.1.1) (Name2.1.1.8) ()              ()
(Name2) (Name2.1) (Name2.1.2) (Name2.1.2.1) (Name2.1.2.1.9) ()
(Name5) (Name5.1) (Name5.1.3) (Name5.1.3.1) (Name5.1.3.1.1) ()
```

This is the code I have so far and I cannot seem to get even the first column right

```
 Public Sub CategoryTest()
      Dim rng As Range
      Dim row As Range
      Dim cell As Range
      Dim Column As Range
      Dim i                                            As Long
      Dim j                                            As Long
      Dim sValue                                       As String
      Dim lTotal                                       As Long

Set rng = Selection

On Error GoTo ErrHandlr
      Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.DisplayAlerts = True
      lTotal = Selection.Cells.Count
        Dim bEntireColumn As Boolean
        Dim bEntireRow As Boolean
        With Selection
            bEntireColumn = .Address = .EntireColumn.Address
            bEntireRow = .Address = .EntireRow.Address
        End With
        If bEntireColumn Then GoTo ErrHandlr
        If bEntireRow Then GoTo ErrHandlr


For Each cell In rng.Column

If cell.Value = "" Then cell.Value = ""
If cell.Value = "1" Then cell.Value = "Name1"
If cell.Value = "2" Then cell.Value = "Name2"
If cell.Value = "3" Then cell.Value = "Name3"
If cell.Value = "4" Then cell.Value = "Name4"
If cell.Value = "5" Then cell.Value = "Name5"
If cell.Value = "6" Then cell.Value = "Name6"
If cell.Value = "7" Then cell.Value = "Name7"
If cell.Value = "8" Then cell.Value = "Name8"
If cell.Value = "9" Then cell.Value = "Name9"
If cell.Value = "10" Then cell.Value = "Name10"
If cell.Value = "11" Then cell.Value = "Name11"

Next cell
GoTo ExitSub
ErrHandlr:
      MsgBox "Sorry, something unexpected when wrong." & vbNewLine & _
             "Make Sure Entire Row Or Column Is Not Selected", vbCritical
ExitSub:

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trick here will be to create a kind of category name database. An array of arrays would be simplest but if each category has a different number of items then you might want to look at the `Collection` object.

It'll also be easier if you read the range into an array, convert the cat numbers into names, and then write the same array back to the range.

I don't want to write your whole project for you, but below is a sample to get you started with just three categories:

```
Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim cats As Collection
    Dim entries As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cat As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long

    Set cats = AcquireCategories

    'You'll need to write the range defintion to suit your needs
    With Selection
        Set rng = .Worksheet.Cells(.Rows(1).Row, "S").Resize(.Rows.Count, 6)
    End With
    entries = rng.Value2

    'Loop through the entry values to convert to categories
    For r = 1 To UBound(entries, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(entries, 2)
            If Not IsEmpty(entries(r, c)) Then
                cat = Empty
                On Error Resume Next
                cat = cats(CStr(c)).item(CStr(entries(r, c)))
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not IsEmpty(cat) Then
                    entries(r, c) = cat
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    rng.Value = entries
End Sub
Private Function AcquireCategories() As Collection
    Dim cat1 As Collection
    Dim cat2 As Collection
    Dim cat3 As Collection

    Set AcquireCategories = New Collection

    Set cat1 = New Collection
    cat1.Add "AA", "1"
    cat1.Add "BB", "2"
    cat1.Add "CC", "3"
    AcquireCategories.Add cat1, "1"

    Set cat2 = New Collection
    cat2.Add "DDD", "1"
    cat2.Add "EEE", "2"
    cat2.Add "FFF", "3"
    AcquireCategories.Add cat2, "2"

    Set cat3 = New Collection
    cat3.Add "GGGG", "1"
    cat3.Add "HHHH", "2"
    cat3.Add "IIII", "3"
    AcquireCategories.Add cat3, "3"

End Function
```

Comment: Thank You for your quick response! But this doesn't take into account different names for subcategories with the same number but a different above category example: (1) (1) (2) [line break] (2) (1) (2) the 1st line has a main category of (1) lets say its clothing and a subcategory of (1) lets say its socks 2nd line has a main category of (2) lets say its electronics and a subcategory of (1) lets say its speakers The subcategories need to be dependent on the categories to the left of them. How do I do this?

Comment: the result of cat3 is dependent on cat2, as would cat2 be on cat1

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution
I combined the categories with a custom function placing a delimiter between them

```
Public Function combine(WorkRng As Range, Optional Sign As String = ".") As String
'Update 20160817
Dim Rng As Range
Dim OutStr As String
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    If Rng.Text <> "," Then
        OutStr = OutStr & Rng.Text & Sign
    End If
Next
OutStr = Replace(OutStr, Sign & Sign & Sign & Sign, Sign, , , vbTextCompare)
OutStr = Replace(OutStr, Sign & Sign & Sign, Sign, , , vbTextCompare)
OutStr = Replace(OutStr, Sign & Sign, Sign, , , vbTextCompare)

OutStr = Left(OutStr, Len(OutStr) - 1)
combine = OutStr
End Function
```

Then I replaced each category number with its corresponding name (including delimeter)
Of course, the procedure was too large so I separated the replacements into multiple custom functions

```
Public Function Categories_1(p_strText As String) As String
Dim strtemp As String
strtemp = p_strText

strtemp = Replace(strtemp, "|1.1.1|", "MainCat|SubCat1|SubCat2", , , vbTextCompare)
Categories_1 = strtemp
End Function
Public Function Categories_2(p_strText As String) As String
Dim strtemp As String
strtemp = p_strText

strtemp = Replace(strtemp, "|2.1.1|", "MainCat|SubCat1|SubCat2", , , vbTextCompare)
Categories_2 = strtemp
End Function
Public Function Categories_3(p_strText As String) As String
Dim strtemp As String
strtemp = p_strText

strtemp = Replace(strtemp, "|3.1.1|", "MainCat|SubCat1|SubCat2", , , vbTextCompare)
Categories_3 = strtemp
End Function
```

*ect.. ect..*
Then I called all of these public functions with a seperate function

```
Public Function Categories(p_strText As String) As String
Dim strtemp As String
strtemp = "|" & p_strText & "|"
strtemp = Categories_1(strtemp)
strtemp = Categories_2(strtemp)
strtemp = Categories_3(strtemp)
strtemp = Categories_4(strtemp)
strtemp = Categories_5(strtemp)
If strtemp = "||" Then strtemp = ""
If Left(strtemp, 1) = "|" Then strtemp = Replace(Mid(strtemp, 2, Len(strtemp) - 2), ".", "|")
Categories = strtemp
End Function
```

Lastly, I seperated the cell based on the specified delimiter in the name "|"

**SOLUTION FOUND!!!** *(he says rubbing his aching forhead that just won a fight with a keyboard)*